# Using hardlink to .git instead of git worktree

Tags: git, git-worktree

There is a known bug in Eclipse which prevents it from working with git worktree.

The only practical work-around I can think of is creating .git hardlink from secondary (branch) working copy to the primary one containing the real .git folder.

What might be the negative consequences of such a work-around (on Windows platform)?

Comment: You would essentially have 2 working folders both hardwired to the same .git folder. Depending on which folder you're in you might incorrect results.

Comment: Your first problem will be that you can't create a hard-link to a directory. You could probably use a "junction" (re-parse point) though. It might be useful to explain what you're trying to achieve, i.e. why you're not just switching branches or using two separate working copies.

Comment: It would be cleaner to just have a second clone of the repository. Even if it were possible to hard link directories, that wouldn't work -- when Lasse says "might get incorrect results" he means "will definitely give you incorrect results". One directory would have working files that correspond to a branch other than the one git thinks is checked out.

Comment: How about just flipping the script: Give Eclipse the real .git directory, and let the others be worktrees. (You don't want two working folders believing that they are the primary. They would corrupt each other. For example, they would share an index.)

Comment: Most operating systems will not *allow* you to create a hard-link to a directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably don't want to do this.  A worktree includes its own version of `HEAD`, the `HEAD` reflog, and the index.  This is required because you have two separate branches checked out and you can stage files in each worktree independent of the other one.

If you hardlinked `.git` into another directory, you'll actually have the same `HEAD`, so you'll be on the same branch.  Also, you'll have the same index, so as soon as you run `git status` in one directory, running it in the other directory will cause every file to be re-read.  That's in addition to the fact that if you run `git add` in one directory, it will be reflected in the other as well.

As a result, this is likely to lead to a bunch of unhappiness and possibly some repository corruption.  If you want to continue to use Eclipse, use separate clones, or you can use a different editor if you want to use worktrees.